# supervisord gave up nodejs entered FATAL state

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, supervisord, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying a node app to aws eb, here is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM    ubuntu:14.04

RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

# Install base packages
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    zsh \
    vim \
    git \
    curl \
    build-essential \
    nodejs \
    npm \
    supervisor

RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/node node /usr/bin/nodejs 10

RUN mkdir -p /var/run/sshd /var/log/supervisor

COPY build/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

RUN mkdir -p /app
ADD api/ /app

RUN cd /app && npm install

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 8090

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

Here is my `supervisord.conf`

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:nodejs]
directory=/app
command=node server.js web
autorestart = true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/%(program_name)s.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/%(program_name)s.log
```

Here is my `stdouterr.log`

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/options.py:295: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
2016-04-08 16:48:37,892 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2016-04-08 16:48:37,892 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf" during parsing
2016-04-08 16:48:37,909 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2016-04-08 16:48:37,909 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2016-04-08 16:48:37,910 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2016-04-08 16:48:38,912 INFO spawned: 'nodejs' with pid 11
2016-04-08 16:48:39,332 INFO exited: nodejs (exit status 8; not expected)
2016-04-08 16:48:40,334 INFO spawned: 'nodejs' with pid 13
2016-04-08 16:48:40,732 INFO exited: nodejs (exit status 8; not expected)
2016-04-08 16:48:42,736 INFO spawned: 'nodejs' with pid 15
2016-04-08 16:48:43,414 INFO exited: nodejs (exit status 8; not expected)
2016-04-08 16:48:46,419 INFO spawned: 'nodejs' with pid 17
2016-04-08 16:48:47,288 INFO exited: nodejs (exit status 8; not expected)
2016-04-08 16:48:48,289 INFO gave up: nodejs entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

Any advice is helpful at this point.

Comment: Is your node app crashing? Try a minimal node app, instead. Also try printing from node to stdout to debug what's going wrong inside.

Comment: You were right, @AssafLavie my node app was crashing because my node and npm versions where not set to the right ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @AssafLavie in the comments mentioned the node app was crashing. The reason it was crashing was because I had to set the `node` and `npm` version to the specified versions in my `package.json` file.

My `Dockerfile` now looks like

```
FROM    ubuntu:14.04

RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

# Install base packages
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    zsh \
    vim \
    git \
    curl \
    build-essential \
    nodejs \
    npm \
    supervisor

RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/node node /usr/bin/nodejs 10

# Added the following 5 lines

RUN npm install -g n

RUN n 5.0.0

RUN rm /usr/bin/node
RUN ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/bin/node

RUN npm install npm@3.8.5 -g

# End of the added lines to specify node and npm versions

RUN mkdir -p /var/run/sshd /var/log/supervisor

COPY build/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

RUN mkdir -p /app
ADD api/ /app

RUN cd /app && npm install

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 8090

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```